# How to get the duration length of an mp3 file from a URL

Tags: c#, .net, naudio

I have a requirement to get the length in seconds from an audio file. All I am given is the URL of the file. I have tried with the NAudio library but when I try using a URL as source I get the error-

> The given path's format is not supported

Below is the code-

```
 Mp3FileReader reader = new Mp3FileReader(RecordingURL);
 Result = reader.TotalTime
```

Comment: Why don't you download the file first?

Answer (score 1):

`Mp3FileReader` cannot open files from a URL, but `MediaFoundationReader` can, so you should try that instead.